# Presto SQL / Athena: how to return only hours, minutes and seconds, from "interval day to second"

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I have a query that from two timestamps calculates the difference and returns as a result a "interval day to second" like this:

```sql
SELECT (interval '1' second)*(timestamp_1 - timestamp_2) as time_delta
```

The result returned look like this:

```sql
  |  time_delta
--+----------------
  | 0 03:28:47.000
  | 0 02:20:37.000
  | 0 00:55:12.000

etc...
```

and the typeof() that result is "interval day to second".

Is there a way to keep only the hour-minute and second part? So that I would get something like:

```sql
  |  time_delta
--+----------------
  |   03:28:47
  |   02:20:37
  |   00:55:12
```

or, at the very least, remove the "day" part?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presto does not have functions to format `interval` values. Your options:

`cast` to `varchar` + [`regexp_replace`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html#regexp_replace):

```
presto:default> SELECT regexp_replace(CAST(parse_duration('3789s') AS varchar), '^0 (.*)\.000', '$1');
  _col0
----------
 01:03:09
```

or [`hour()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#hour), `minute()` and `second()` functions + concatenate.
This is greatly simplified by the [`format()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/conversion.html#format) function, but that's not available on Athena yet.

Comment: I figured that in the end I would end up using some regex to edit the result casted as a string. Thanks, I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @wtfzambo please create an issue https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues, we may be able to add something helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the presto convienience function for the timestamp that you get back. It looks like presto supports the MySQL function format so you should be able to use  `date_parse` based on the presto docs.

Something like

```
SELECT date_parse((interval '1' second)*(timestamp_1 - timestamp_2), %r) as time_delta
```

More info here:
https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work because "date_parse" is expecting a "varchar" value, whereas my column is an "interval".
Even casting the interval as string, I get and "invalid format" error, probably due to how the time_delta is formatted, since it's not exactly a date, but just a duration.

Comment: What is the purpose of this part of your query? `interval '1' second` That is the reason you're getting an interval back.  Can you remove that and use `date_diff`?

Comment: It's some clickstream data of an app, timestamp_1 and timestamp_2 represent the first and last interaction of a single user. The difference shows me how much time they spent on it.
I had actually tried "date_diff" to begin with, but the output of that function is a "bigint".

Tbh the result I'm getting with the original query is already okish, I just wanted to make it more readable by removing "day" and "milliseconds" from it.

Comment: What unit did you pass to date_diff? should be able to pass minutes to date diff and then calculate hours and minutes from it by dividing by 60 and using mod 60 for the minutes part.

Comment: Milliseconds, yeah that was the alternative solution I had in mind. I was just hoping there would have been a quick function that did it for me in one line.